# Encrypting and decrypting passwords with php

Tags: php, security, encryption, passwords

I want store passwords encrypted in database. For this purpose I use `md5 ();` or `sha1 ();` functions. But if my users send a **password reset** request I want to send them their password instead of **reset link**. But problem is, with both of these functions I can't decrypt passwords. Is there any function that both can encrypt and decrypt strings?

Comment: How are you storing whether or not someone "likes" your post?  If you're already getting that data from the server, then just do a `.show()` on the element that contains your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some sort of notification to appear without the page reloading, you need to use AJAX.

I think the best way to do what your asking is make a database and set a column that gives an id of 0 or 1. If the user clicks it then it sets that id=1. You can then check whether id = 1, and display an message using AJAX.

Look here for more info
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/